# Как получить названия месяцев на украинском языке?

Tags: php, linux, locale

Доступные:

> C C.UTF-8 POSIX en_AG en_AG.utf8 en_AU.utf8 en_BW.utf8 en_CA.utf8
>   en_DK.utf8 en_GB.utf8 en_HK.utf8 en_IE.utf8 en_IN en_IN.utf8 en_NG
>   en_NG.utf8 en_NZ.utf8 en_PH.utf8 en_SG.utf8 en_US.utf8 en_ZA.utf8
>   en_ZM en_ZM.utf8 en_ZW.utf8 ru_RU.utf8 ru_UA.utf8

`ru_UA.utf8` выводит русские....

На Windows есть укр кодировка, проблема на Linux

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_UA.utf8');
echo strftime("%A %d-%m-%y");
```

Comment: И рекомендую всё же уточнить разницу между **локалями** и **кодировками** :)

Answer (score 1):

> ru_UA.utf8 выводит русские....

Естественно, `ru` же, это локаль на **русский** язык. Он многие детали берёт из локали `ru_RU`, в том числе названия месяцев, [вот, взгляните](http://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/ru_UA/).

[Вам нужна `uk_UA`](http://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/uk_UA/), локаль на **украинский**. В приведённом списке доступных локалей её нет.

Если у вас есть контроль над машиной, смотрите по её ОС, как добавить в неё локаль. Для Debian и производных должна помочь перенастройка пакета с локалями:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Отметьте там нужные и подтвердите выбор.

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, 'uk_UA');
Результат: Friday 19-02-16

Comment: @Dana это и ожидалось, да. Ведь в списке этой локали нет.

Comment: в том-то и проблема...себе можно добавить,а другим пользователям как быть?)пусть сами себе устанавливают?

Comment: @Dana а какое отношение к пользователям имеет локаль **сервера**?